# YouTube iframe Player API: control MULTIPLE iframe players that are already in the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I know this question has been asked before. However, the answer is out of date and I also need additional info for multiple iframe players.

I followed the code from [Google Developers website](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Examples). However, when I tried to call `event.target.playVideo();`, inside `onPlayerReady(event) function`, the video didn't play when the page first loaded.

I also got this error message `GET https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/M7lc1UVf-VE/sddefault.webp?v=516f0b27 404`

Right now I'm showing the example of 2 videos and `Play video 1`, `Stop video 1`, `Play video 2`, and `Stop video 2` work. When there're are many videos, how do I set up the code so it's more compact to embed them? Thank you for your help.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player1;
var player2;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   
  player1 = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example1', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady1
    }
  });

  player2 = new YT.Player('existing-iframe-example2', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady2
    }
  });

}

function onPlayerReady1(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();

  $(function() {
 
    $('#play-btn1').on('click', function() {
      event.target.playVideo();
    });

    $('#stop-btn1').on('click', function() {
      event.target.stopVideo();
    });

  });
}


function onPlayerReady2(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
 
  $(function() {

    $('#play-btn2').on('click', function() {
      event.target.playVideo();
    });

    $('#stop-btn2').on('click', function() {
      event.target.stopVideo();
    });

  });
}
```

```css
.control { margin-bottom: 30px; }
.play-btn, .stop-btn { display: inline-block; margin: 10px 20px; color: blue; cursor: pointer; }
.play-btn:hover, .stop-btn:hover { color: orange; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="existing-iframe-example1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&controls=1&rel=0&color=white"></iframe>

<div class="control">
  <div id="play-btn1" class="play-btn">Play video 1</div>
  <div id="stop-btn1" class="stop-btn">Stop video 1</div>
</div>


<iframe id="existing-iframe-example2" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5a2oZwB6zX0?autoplay=1&enablejsapi=1&controls=1&rel=0&color=white"></iframe>

<div class="control">
  <div id="play-btn2" class="play-btn">Play video 2</div>
  <div id="stop-btn2" class="stop-btn">Stop video 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2298), this is expected. *What we do is actually try to load `sddefault.jpg`, if that failed we fallback to `hqdefault.jpg` which should exist for all videos.* Also from this [link](https://orbitingweb.com/blog/view-youtube-thumbnail-image/), if the video does not have a max resolution image, you will get a 404 error for the `maxresdefault.jpg` URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer on the error message. The problem is with the video (video id: M7lc1UVf-VE ) that was used in an example on Google Developers website. Once I replaced that test video with a different video, the error is gone. However, there're still two questions left. The first one is the videos didn't play when the page first loaded. The second one is how to make the code more compact to embed multiple YouTube iframe players. Thank you for your help.